# subset data frames in python

Tags: python, dataframe

For example, I have a data frame with 100 rows and 200 columns. How can I select row 1:50, 65 and 70:90; column 1:30, 43 and 50: 100 from this data frame? It is very convenient to do this in R, but I cannot find a convenient way to do this in python.

In R, I can do it this way: df[c(1:50, 65, 70:90), c(1:30, 43, 50:100)]. What is the python equivalent for this line of R code?

What if it is an array?

Thank you.

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html

Comment: Thank you. I have seen this. But it only covers the very basic cases. I still get confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.iloc[]` with lists, so the equivalent would be:

```
df.iloc[list(range(50)) + [64] + list(range(69, 90)), list(range(30)) + [42] + list(range(49, 100))]
```

Comment: What if it is an array?

Comment: [numpy.array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) can be quite different from pandas data frame. Here is how I would index numpy array `df.values[list(range(50)) + [64] + list(range(69, 90)), :][:, list(range(30)) + [42] + list(range(49, 100))]`

Comment: Thank you so much!